# gawk - suppress output of matched lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

I'm running into an issue where `gawk` prints unwanted output. I want to find lines in a file that match an expression, test to see if the information in the line matches a certain condition, and then print the line if it does. I'm getting the output that I want, but `gawk` is also printing every line that matches the expression rather than just the lines that meet the condition.

I'm trying to search through files containing dates and times for certain actions to be executed. I want to show only lines that contain times in the future. The dates are formatted like so:

```
text... 2016-01-22 10:03:41 more text...
```

I tried using `sed` to just print all lines starting with ones that had the current hour, but there is no guarantee that the file contains a line with that hour, (plus there is no guarantee that the lines all have any particular year, month, day etc.) so I needed something more robust. I decided trying to convert the times into seconds since epoch, and comparing that to the current `systime`. If the conversion produces a number greater than `systime`, I want to print that line.

Right now it seems like `gawk`'s `mktime()` function is the key to this. Unfortunately, it requires input in the following format:

```
yyyy mm dd hh mm ss
```

I'm currently searching a test file (called `timecomp`) for a regular expression matching the date format.

Edit: the test file only contains a date and time on each line, no other text.

I used `sed` to replace the date separators (i.e. /, -, and :) with a space, and then piped the output to a gawk script called `stime` using the following statement:

```
sed -e 's/[-://_]/ /g' timecomp | gawk -f stime
```

Here is the script

```
# stime
BEGIN { tsec=systime();  } /.*20[1-9][0-9] [0-1][1-9] [0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9] [0-6][0-9]/ { 
    if (tsec < mktime($0))
        print "\t" $0    # the tab is just to differentiate the desired output from the other lines that are being printed.
} $1
```

Right now this is getting the basic information that I want, but it is also printing every like that matches the original expression, rather than just the lines containing a time in the future. Sample output:

```
2016 01 22 13 23 20
2016 01 22 14 56 57
2016 01 22 15 46 46
2016 01 22 16 32 30
    2016 01 22 18 56 23
2016 01 22 18 56 23
    2016 01 22 22 22 28
2016 01 22 22 22 28
    2016 01 22 23 41 06
2016 01 22 23 41 06
    2016 01 22 20 32 33
```

How can I print only the lines in the future?

Note: I'm doing this on a Mac, but I want it to be portable to Linux because I'm ultimately making this for some tasks I have to do at work.

I'd like trying to accomplish this in one script rather than requiring the `sed` statement to reformat the dates, but I'm running into other issues that probably require a different question, so I'm sticking to this for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

**Answered:** I had a `$1` at the last line of my script, and that was the cause of the additional output.

Comment: What's the $1 at the end for?

Comment: Does your file not contain *any* of `-:/_` outside of the date? Because at the moment your replacing these globally with spaces. Also, why are you replacing `/` and `_`? They're not part of the date string.

Comment: `$0` is still the complete record including `text` and `more text`; don't you want `mktime` to only get the date/time part as arguments?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Thank you - that was it. I figured it was something simple like that, but this was driving me insane. I'm new to writing awk scripts, and I was thinking that the $1 was needed for some reason, and it clearly is not!

Comment: @BenjaminW. - The input files very well may contain those characters in other positions, but this is just a test case to get something working. I'll be making that expression more exclusive once I get things to the point where I can run it on the actual files. You are also right about the $0 - once again, that wasn't an issue since I limited the test file to only contain dates and times. I thought I had mentioned that, but I clearly did not. I'll be making an edit to make that more clear for other readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of awk, this is an (almost) pure Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Regex for time string
re='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}'

# Current time, in seconds since epoch
now=$(date +%s)

while IFS= read -r line; do

    # Match time string
    [[ $line =~ $re ]]
    time_string="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"

    # Convert time string to seconds since epoch
    time_secs=$(date -d "$time_string" +%s)

    # If time is in the future, print line
    if (( time_secs > now )); then
        echo "$line"
    fi

done < <(grep 'pattern' "$1")
```

This takes advantage of the Coreutils `date` formatting to convert a date to seconds since epoch for easy comparison of two dates:

```
$ date
Fri, Jan 22, 2016 11:23:59 PM
$ date +%s
1453523046
```

And the `-d` argument to take a string as input:

```
$ date -d '2016-01-22 10:03:41' +%s
1453475021
```

The script does the following:

- Filter the input file with grep (for lines containing a generic `pattern`, but could be anything)
- Loop over lines containing `pattern`
- Match the line with a regex that matches the date/time string `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and extract the match
- Convert the time string to seconds since epoch
- Compare that value to the time in `$now`, which is the current date/time in seconds since epoch
- If the time from the logfile is in the future, print the line

For an example input file like this one

```
text 2016-01-22 10:03:41 with time in the past
more text 2016-01-22 10:03:41 matching pattern but in the past
other text 2017-01-22 10:03:41 in the future matching pattern
some text 2017-01-23 10:03:41 in the future but not matching
blahblah 2022-02-22 22:22:22 pattern and also in the future
```

the result is

```
$ date
Fri, Jan 22, 2016 11:36:54 PM
$ ./future_time logfile
other text 2017-01-22 10:03:41 in the future matching pattern
blahblah 2022-02-22 22:22:22 pattern and also in the future
```

Comment: Outstanding! I've been playing with a bash implementation of this, and I've gotten it to work with some limited success, but unfortunately there are multiple files that I intend to use this for, and many of them have wildly different date/time formats. 

I've tried different approaches with bash, but eventually ran into a wall becuase I was completely unaware of BASH_REMATCH and the regex comparison operator until you posted this. (I wrote my first bash function about two or three months ago, so I have a lot to learn!). 

Thank you! I got the awk version working, but this will still be useful!

Comment: Sorry, I fat-fingered the return key! Haha thanks again!

Comment: @Boncrete `date -d` is very smart about the date string - almost any format is parsed properly! But the Bash regex would have to be updated, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have working now. It works for a few different date formats and on the actual files that have more than just the date and time. The default format that it works for is yyyy/mm/dd, but it takes an argument to specify a mm/dd/yyyy format if needed.

```
BEGIN { tsec=systime(); dtstr=""; dt[1]="" } /.*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ { 
cur=$0

if ( fm=="mdy" ) {
    match($0,/[0-1][1-9][-_\/][0-3][0-9][-_\/]20[1-9][0-9]/)        # mm dd yyyy
    section=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    split(section, dt, "[-_//]")
    dtstr=dt[3] " " dt[1] " " dt[2]
    gsub(/[0-1][1-9][-\/][0-3][0-9][-\/]20[1-9][0-9]/, dtstr, cur)
}

gsub(/[-_:/,]/, " ", cur)
match(cur,/20[1-9][0-9] [0-1][1-9] [0-3][0-9][[:space:] ]*[0-2][0-9] [0-6][0-9] [0-6][0-9]/)
arr=mktime(substr(cur,RSTART,RLENGTH))

if ( tsec < arr)
    print $0
}
```

I'll be adding more format options as I find more formats, but this works for all the different files I've tested so far. If they have a mm/dd/yyyy format, you call it with:

```
gawk -f stime fm=mdy filename
```

I plan on adding an option to specify the time window that you want to see, but this is an excellent start. Thank you guys again, this is going to drastically simplify a few tasks at work ( I basically have to retrieve a great deal of data, often under time pressure depending on the situation ).

Comment: An awk solution will be much faster than my Bash based one, by the way. Bash is slow.